# how to create browser view for larval backend admin panel

Tags: android, laravel, uiwebview, react-native

how to create browser view for larval backend admin panel ..currently app is working fine so help on creating website access from browser
backend is setup on domain and same is accessed by android app via api now i have to enable browser view for frontend on desktop which will give second option for customer to access products
Solution tried:
To access same content of android app via html but not working